# Why the command of cordova to sign an apk file has an extra -- without any arguments?

Tags: android, cordova

I want to learn more about signing an apk file with cordova. The documentation has the following command:

```
cordova run android --release -- --keystore=../my-release-key.keystore --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name --password=password --packageType=bundle
```

Why next to release, there are -- without any arguments?

Here is the link to the documentation of cordova for signing apk files:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/10.x/guide/platforms/android/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is called "end-of-options-marker". Precise definition is:

> The first -- argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the '-' character.

In most use cases in Cordova/NPM world, -- is used to separate options meant for the main command, while things after -- are options for whatever nested command they run.

In your example `run android --release` are arguments of the Cordova CLI itself, while things after the -- (`--keystore=../my-release-key.keystore --storePassword=password --alias=alias_name --password=password --packageType=bundle`) are extra parameters passed as-is to Gradle in case of Cordova.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: To be more precise, this is how it works for your command - cordova run android goes to platforms/android/cordova/run script, which then uses the arguments after the -- command.  That results in running platforms/android/cordova/lib/run.js, which then runs platforms/android/cordova/lib/build.js, which uses those arguments.

Comment: I use. Thank you.